# "Multiple Google Analytics tags detected"

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

In order to try and debug a client's Google Analytics account (linked to their website), I installed [Tag assistant by Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en).

It returned the following message:

[image]

<sup>*"Multiple Google Analytics tags detected".*</sup>

The first one is the one I placed in the body of the webpages. The second one seems to come from "http://twitbridge.com/ads/include.js?app=marioghostNaN".
Tag assistant says "*Tag is included in an external script file*".

There are .js files related to a light box I installed, as well as the HTML theme's original .js files (I didn't make the theme).
I have tried removing all the .js links referenced in the page, as well as deleting the .js folder of the FTP. Each time, Tag assistant would still find the twitbridge/marioghost analytics script in the page and result in multiple tags being detected.

[image]

Google Tag assistant gives me the *Metadata*, the *Code snippets* and the *Cookies* related to this tracker, but I cannot seem to find what "calls" it in my files. I also couldn't find anything while launching a search within contents of the website's files that are on a local backup.

[Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) also sees it, but seems to indicate that this "marioghost" tracker is related to a .js file hosted by Google Analytics themselves (which is super confusing):

[image]

**How do I find out what script calls this analytics tracker, and how to disable it to see if it fixes the main issue?**

Comment: Are there any iFrames on the site?

Comment: No iframes on the website (searching for "frame" and "iframe" in the code returned 0).

Comment: You also have searched for mario, dimension, as25n45 ....?
What happens if you delete your own ga stuff? Is it still tracking to the second propery?

Comment: Searching these terms within files of the FTP returned 0 results. Removing my GA Google script, plus all the .JS files of the theme and the .JS files of the lightbox on the FTP side removes my tracker, but the other one remains, even if I delete all the CSS folder (I thought there might be a call to files there too...).

Answer (score 0):

Chromes network tab has a column named "initiator" (you might need to enable it first, not sure it is visible by default) that shows you which document or script issued a request (grey in the screenshot):

[image]

Look for a call to "/collect?v=1..." with the UAID of  the rogue account in the url and then look for the initiator.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm having the same problem, same results if I look in the network tab.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, can not find anything